# Mongoose model, trigger middleware using MongoDB Compass

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this model middleware which works fine in runtime, but if I use MongoDB Compass to delete a 'Class' document, it doesn't work. I tryed the 'remove' method but errors this in VSCode:

> Argument of type '"remove"' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'RegExp | "insertMany"'.

```js
classSchema.post<ClassInterface>('deleteOne', { document: true, query: false }, async function (doc) {
  const classItem = doc;
  // console.log(classItem);
  const Event = model('Event');
  const Shift = model('Shift');
  const Subscription = model('Subscription');
  try {
    const events: EventInterface[] = await Event.find({ class: classItem._id });
    for (const event of events) {
      await Shift.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: event.shifts } });
    }
    await Event.deleteMany({ class: classItem._id });
    await Subscription.updateMany(
      { classes: classItem._id },
      { $pull: { classes: classItem._id } }
    );

  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Error deleting related documents:', error);
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the premise of the question. Is it asking if you can trigger mongoose middleware when directly modifying documents in the database via Compass (to which the answer is: "no")? Or is it some other issue entirely? Could you provide some more specifics about your configuration and what actions you are taking to cause the problematic behavior?

Comment: @user20042973 I would like to delete in cascade all related documents when I use MongoDB Compass to delete a 'Class' document.

Comment: Which line throws this error? Show the full error stack and related code.

Comment: @LinDu if I use 'remove'  instead 'deleteOne' it figures underlined and VSCode displays that error.